# memcpy to string buffer defined in macro

Tags: c, string, macros, memcpy

i am using avrx to build a software run on custom tiny device, but i'm still newbie to C.
As indicated by makefile, it's using "c99 plus GCC extensions".
Today i finally ran into a piece of code written by some old colleague, it made me very confused:

```
#define SOMEDATA    "ABC"
void main(void)
{
    memcpy(SOMEDATA, "OK", sizeof("OK"));
    printf(SOMEDATA);//it works just fine?!?!?  

    memcpy(SOMEDATA, "VERY_LONG", sizeof("VERY_LONG"));
    printf(SOMEDATA);//well, now it go nuts. all i see is some random data.
}
```

Why?
Why the logic in `main()` behaved like that? I used to thought that MACROs acts like constant and cannot be modified.

Comment: Macros are a red herring - they're just code copy-and-paste.  Once you've substituted the macros, does the resulting code make sense?

Comment: Reason `"VERY LONG"` fails is probably because it overflows the allocated chunk of memory for `"ABC"`.

Comment: @SkyLeeCorp  This says about the stability of the firm where you are working. The old colleague and the new one the both do not know C.:)

Comment: yeah, when i change the macro into some real string like "Z", it works too.

Comment: "Code written by some old colleague" - my sincere advice to you is: "run for your life!"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Starting with this kind of curiosity,  i add this kind of long assignment on purpos.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Good to know anothoer kind of solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
  memcpy(SOMEDATA, "OK", sizeof("OK"));
```

which is the same as

```
  memcpy("ABC", "OK", sizeof("OK"));
```

is a very *unusual* way of attempting to modify a string literal. It  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Same as in the other case and, as we know, the outcome of UB is, well, anything.

That said,

```
   printf(SOMEDATA);
```

may be valid but a poor practice, if there's no conversion required, safer to use `puts()` or `fputs()`.

Finally,

> *I used to thought that MACROs acts like constant and cannot be modified.*

Well, probably you're interested in `#define` statements. `#define` statements are textual replacements which takes place at compile time. In case, a literal (or constant) value is used as a define statement, yes, it cannot be changed (following the property of a constant or literal) but in case, a define statement defines a variable name, then that variable, if a modifiable lvalue, can be modified for sure.

**TL;DR** `#define` statements are textual replacement, and their alteration depends on the element in replacement list.

Comment: Thank you for explaination, it helps a lot! But i would preffer the compiler giving some complains.

Comment: @SkyLeeCorp well, you can use `-Wwrite-strings` with gcc to get _some_ hints. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

This quote from the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals) will be useful for you

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

The first statement of the quote says that two string literals with the same values can be stored in the static memory either as distinct arrays or as the same one array,

So in fact this expression in the condition of the if statement

```
#define SOMEDATA    "ABC"

//...

if ( SOMEDATA == SOMEDATA )
{
    //...
}
```

can yield either true or false depending on the settings of options of the compiler.

That is these two calls of `memcpy`

```
memcpy(SOMEDATA, "OK", sizeof("OK"));
//..
memcpy(SOMEDATA, "VERY_LONG", sizeof("VERY_LONG"));
```

that are equivalent to

```
memcpy("ABC", "OK", sizeof("OK"));
//..
memcpy("ABC", "VERY_LONG", sizeof("VERY_LONG"));
```

can write either to the same extent of memory or to different extents of memory.

The second statement of the quote says that any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior of the program.

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters used in a hosted environment shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
^^^^
```

Though some compilers as the Microsoft compiler allows to use the type void as the return type of main it is better to follow the C Standard.